# Connecting MySQL workbench to Amazon RDS instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGDZb.png)While connecting MySQL workbench to Amazon RDS instance, am getting this error.

/**
Connecting to MySQL server ...
Can't connect to MySQL server on 'aa58nt64hgc91d.cuh2vqc4pep5.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (110)
**/

Please help me to resolve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Copy and paste your DB security group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may start checking from basics,

1. If you are accessing the URI from public, please check the Subnet properties to confirm that they have Internet Gateway attached.
2. Check whether security group allows access to port 3306.

Did you set it as publicly available while creating the RDS.
 [image]

Comment: I just created RDS instance and tried to connect it from MySQL workbench. I set this publicly accessibility to 'Yes' while creating the RDS. But I didn't see any description like this while selecting that. There is only 'Yes' or 'No' option. Am new to this. Is there anything I missed out here?

Comment: I'm also trying to do the same. Not able to connect yet. Hope you found the solution for this issue. @Anila

Answer (score 0):

Try `telnet aa58nt64hgc91d.cuh2vqc4pep5.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com 3306`.

Verify that your security group permits port 3306 access.

Answer (score 0):

Biggest problem is the firewall. In AWS this is the Security Group -> Inbound Rules. You need to open port 3306 (listed as MYSQL/Aurora) to whatever IP address your MySQL client is running on. Unless you absolutely must (unlikely), do NOT open it up to the whole world - limit to the IPs of the server(s) that will directly access the RDS database.